# Formatting Datetime field in a Symfony2 form to display full months

Tags: forms, datetime, symfony, rendering

I am using a formType in Symfony2, and one of the fields is of type DateTime.
I would like to display the months as full months (and preferably in a language other than English).

If my field type had been birthday, thus without time, it would have been easy:

```
$builder->add('appointment', 'birthday', array
(
  'format' => 'dd - MMMM - yyyy',
  'widget' => 'choice'
  'required'  => true
));
```

But the field is now defined as:

```
$builder->add('appointment', 'datetime', array
(
  'required'  => true
  // ????
));
```

How can I render this field type using 5 dropdown lists (day, month, year, hour, minute), with the months being full text items? And how can I define an array with the month names in another language?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create your own field type by choosing the birthday type as a parent. You can follow these simple [steps](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) to do this.

---

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class AppointmentType extends AbstractType{

    //...

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'birthday';
    }
```